# Accessing Android Activity state with Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-lifecycle

I'm quite new to Unity3d development. I'm trying to build an android app using Unity3d. Wondering how is it possible to get Activity state OR how to implement Android life cycle using Unity3d ?

Comment: im also new to unity, i have a script that recognizes the back button, would you like to have it? the home button works as it should though

Answer (score 0):

In general, Unity handles most of this internally, and as far as I know there is very little visibility to any of this unless you use a plug-in (maybe something like prime31's Etcetera plugin might help). I've published about half a dozen Android apps with Unity and you generally don't have to worry about it.

The one thing you'll definitely want to handle is MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause() which is what gets called by most state transitions in Android with Unity (the two biggies being incoming phone calls, and user pushing home button, then returning from either of those).

The [Handheld](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Handheld.html) class might also be of use depending on what you're looking for.

But the best way to learn is just build a simple app and deploy to an Android device, it's actually the easiest of the mobile platforms to develop and publish for in Unity (IMHO).